# Data structure to use when gathering response from async calls

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, async-await, task

I am running this piece of code in my application.

```
public Task<BulkResponse<JObject>> GetRelatedObjectsAsync(IEnumerable<PrimaryObjectInfo> primaryObjectInfos)
{
    var allSecondaries = new List<Tuple<int, List<JObject>>>();
    var exceptionsDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Exception>();

    var relatedObjectsTasks = primaryObjectInfos.Select(async primaryObjectInfo =>
    {
        try
        {
            var secondaryObject = await objectManager.GetRelatedObjectsAsync(primaryObjectInfo);
            allSecondaries.Add(Tuple.Create(primaryObjectInfo.Index, secondaryObject.ToList()));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exceptionsDict.TryAdd(primaryObjectInfo.Index,  ex);
        }
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(relatedObjectsTasks);

    return ConvertToBulkResponse(allSecondaries, exceptionsDict);
}
```

When I run this code `allSecondaries` object sometimes returns valid list of results and sometimes the code ends up catching exceptions for the parallel threads I have for each `primaryObjectInfo`.

Async method `objectManager.GetRelatedObjectsAsync()` internally call 4-5 async functions and there are functions where parameters are passed by reference. (ref keyword)

**Question:** 
Am I using the right data structure to consolidate the result from all parallel threads ? 
If yes, what could be the reason I am getting different result every time?

Comment: `List<T>` is not thread-safe, you cannot use it in scenarios where it could be modified concurrently. Use one of the collection types from the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace instead. Alternatively, you could make each task return their own individual tuple, and collect each tuple from the respective `Task<T>` object after the tasks have completed (basically avoiding to touch `allSecondaries` in a task altogether)

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to get successful results from a Task.WhenAll when one of the tasks fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55887028/is-it-possible-to-get-successful-results-from-a-task-whenall-when-one-of-the-tas)

Answer (score 0):

You'd better split the execution from the results gathering:

```
public Task<BulkResponse<JObject>> GetRelatedObjectsAsync(
    IEnumerable<PrimaryObjectInfo> primaryObjectInfos)
{
    var relatedObjectsTasks = primaryObjectInfos
        .Select(
            async primaryObjectInfo =>
                (primaryObjectInfo.Index,
                 await objectManager.GetRelatedObjectsAsync(primaryObjectInfo)))
        .ToList();

    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(relatedObjectsTasks);
    }
    catch
    {
        // observe each task's, exception
    }

    var allSecondaries = new List<(int index, List<JObject> related)>();
    var exceptionsDict = new Dictionary<int, Exception>();

    foreach (var relatedObjectsTask in relatedObjectsTasks)
    {
        try
        {
            allSecondaries.Add(relatedObjectsTask.Result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exceptionsDict.Add(relatedObjectsTask.index,  ex);
        }
    }

    return ConvertToBulkResponse(allSecondaries, exceptionsDict);
}
```

You could look into each task's `IsFaulted`/`Exception` and `IsCancelled` properties instead of causing exceptions to be thrown:

```
    foreach (var relatedObjectsTask in relatedObjectsTasks)
    {
        if (relatedObjectsTask.IsCancelled)
        {
            exceptionsDict.Add(
                relatedObjectsTask.index,
                new TaskCancelledException(relatedObjectsTask));
        }
        else if (relatedObjectsTask.IsFaulted)
        {
            exceptionsDict.TryAdd(relatedObjectsTask.index,  ex);
        }
        else
        {
            allSecondaries.Add(relatedObjectsTask.Result);
        }
    }
```